# How to measure capacitive coupling on pcb traces?

Tags: coupling

I have bare PCB board (6 layers) with me and I would like to see if my switching signals (60 kHz) have any effect on the sensitive current measurement lines.

I just want to know if there is quick test by sending a pulse on one trace and checking the other trace on oscilloscope.I would like to know the test setup?
How should these traces be terminated and by how much resistance?

Comment: Capable e-CAD software usually have this very feature.

Comment: I think you can do it just by measuring the signal amplitude on the victim trace when you apply a function to the agressor trace. Basically the coupling acts as an unknown capacitor between agressor and victim. By placing different real capacitors on the victim trace (to ground) and observing the effect on amplitude, you can work out the size of the capacitor between them. Should work. I have never done it that way.